# Python reading 2 strings from the same line

Tags: python, file, readline

how can I  read once at a time 2 strings from a txt file, that are written on the same line?

e.g.
francesco 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# out is your file
out.readline().split() # result is ['francesco', '10']
```

Assuming that your two strings are separated by whitespace. You can split based on any string (comma, colon, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not read just the line and split it up later? You'd have to read byte-by-byte and look for the space character, which is very inefficient. Better to read the entire line, and then split the resulting string on the space, giving you two strings.

Comment: Really? [line.split() for line in open('somefile.txt','r')]

Comment: May be one line of code, but it's still doing what I described: read a line, and split it.

Answer (score 0):

```
'francesco 10'.split()
```

will give you `['francesco', '10']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in fi:
    line.split()
```

Its ideal to just iterate over a file object.